# get stdout of all nested child process in node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, process, pipe, ipc

I have created a node script to launch a child process, and I have been successful in redirecting its stdout to console.

But in case child process creates a nested child process, then I am unable to get its stdout or stdin.

I have a vague idea that I have to create stream and pipe it to parent process, but I am not sure about it now.

Can someone please give an approach to how accomplish it.

Below is my current code to launch child process

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
ls = spawn "ruby" , [ @editor.getPath() ]
ls.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString()
ls.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Relevant link: [Node API documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio)

- If your need is to get the child's (and grandchild's) data in your streams, best option is to inherit the streams:

`spawn('prg', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });`

- If your need is to get the children data into custom objects, the use pipe, and then install stream data callbacks - such as what you did already.
- If the 1st level child is a node process, it needs to spawn the grandchild through 'inherit' model, for both the data to be available to the parent.
- Otherwise, the child has to spawn with 'pipe' and install handler, and then feed them into appropriate streams: for example, write grandchild's error into child's stderr, and so on.
- If the grandchild is non-node program, 'inherit' is the desired model.
- If the child is non-node, it may not be possible to get the grandchild data, as the availability of data will depend on how the child process spawns the grandchild and treat its streams.

Hope this helps.